# can't output gray scaled image I've created using add_image_size

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails, actions, images

I am trying to create a gray scaled image of the image I upload. I have been able to upload the image and create the gray scaled version by using this code:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','bw_images_size');
function bw_images_size() {
    $crop = get_option('thumbnail_crop')==1 ? true : false;
    add_image_size('thumbnail-bw', '', '', $crop);
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','bw_images_filter');
function bw_images_filter($meta) {
    $file = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = $file['basedir'] . '/' . $meta['file'];

    list($orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type) = @getimagesize($file);

    $image = wp_load_image($file);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);


    //imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
    switch ($orig_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $file = str_replace(".gif", "-bw.gif", $file);
            imagegif( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $file = str_replace(".png", "-bw.png", $file);
            imagepng( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $file = str_replace(".jpg", "-bw.jpg", $file);
            imagejpeg( $image, $file );
            break;
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

My issue is when I try and output the image in the template; I just get a duplicate of the coloured version. I output the images like this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    ?>
    <div class='colour_testimonial'>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class='bw_testimonial'>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-bw'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Any ideas why my I can't output my black and white image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the metadata information with the new b&w thumbnail:

```
$meta['sizes']['thumbnail-bw'] = array(
  'width' => $meta['width'], 
  'height' => $meta['height'],
  'file' => $file
);
```

after generating the new image (after the `switch` block).

There 's also a plugin, called [Grayscale](http://wordpress.org/plugins/grayscale/), that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I tried adding your bit of code and i got it to work but i found out that wp_load_image() is depreicated. I tried changing it to using the new function but i can't get that to work so i tried the plugin but that also failed :(

Comment: You're welcome! To avoid using `wp_load_image` you can call [`wp get image editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor) that returns a [`WP Image Editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) object. I suggest you to extend the `WP_Image_Editor_GD` class to add the b&w functionality.

Comment: Hi Thanks again. Do you have any examples I could work from?

Comment: Not too much :( You can see the [`WP_Image_editor_GD`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php) class source and its methods. `rotate` or `flip` methods are not so far away from what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will give that a look and see what i can do. thanks for helping

Comment: This answer did get my issue fixed but i found out i have a more fundamental issue with the funciton being depreciated. so I accepted this as the answerer did fix my issue